# Ipywidgets interact won't apply datepicker to DataFrame ("TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable")

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datepicker, ipywidgets

I'm building a jupyter notebook that uses some interactive widgets to help move through some dataframes.  My jupyter and python experience is limited, and most of my notebook so far is recreating consolidations and calculations I'd previously created in a series of Excel PivotTables.

The first try at an interactive widget worked ok.  It calls up the dataframe, with a sliding widget to limit returned rows by the result of a column (how many days was an assignment opened):

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets
@interact
def days_open_widget(column='days_open', x=(0,2000,5)):
    return df.loc[df[column] > x]
```

Next, I wanted to be able to separately explore the DataFrame using two datepickers to constrain the results by the date the assignment was created.  Parts of it are working, like the datepickers populate with the earliest and latest dates but they are not tied to the dataframe.  Here's the code:

```
interact(df,
        start_date=widgets.DatePicker(value=df.assignment_creation_date.min()),
        end_date=widgets.DatePicker(value=df.assignment_creation_date.max()))
```

After Jupyter displays the datepickers, it follows up with the following error, then displays the unfiltered dataframe.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipywidgets\widgets\interaction.py in update(self, *args)
    254                     value = widget.get_interact_value()
    255                     self.kwargs[widget._kwarg] = value
--> 256                 self.result = self.f(**self.kwargs)
    257                 show_inline_matplotlib_plots()
    258                 if self.auto_display and self.result is not None:

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I'm not sure why trying to access the DataFrame is giving me an "object is not callable" error when I accessed it earlier, or why the DatePickers successfully read the DataFrame column, but then disconnect.

The behavior I'm trying to create would call the entire dataframe, but let me filter the resulting rows between dates selected from the datepicker.  What am I missing?

Edit: I know the code is messy and in hindsight, I don't think I should be importing interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual separately and then be importing all of ipywidgets.

Edit 2: I couldn't get AC24's solution to work, but I think that's more to do with my own inability to properly define a function that filtered the dataframe.  I ended up finding QGrid instead, which has a datepicker along with other filters.

More info on QGrid at https://qgrid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ but if anyone has a more explicit description for how to define the function to pass the dataframe as an function please feel free to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `interact` behaves differently to the `interactive` decorator. When using `interact`, the first argument should be a function/callable that gets called when you change any of the widgets. You passed in the dataframe `df` as the first argument, and therefore `interact` is trying to call `df` as a function with the start_date and end_date keywords. Hence the error, as dataframes are not callable.

Have a look at the documentation for examples, you probably want to build a simple function to filter your dataframe, and use that function name as the first argument to `interact`.

https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html#Basic-interact

Comment: Do you mean a function like the

def filtering_dataframe():
    return

style or do you mean something else?  When I tried to find examples of filtering dataframes, I was getting suggestions like "df.filter(regex ='[aA]')" and I don't know how to incorporate them into the def and return style functions.